# (ASP.NET) Visual Studio 2022 displays errors for files that do not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, compiler-errors

[image]

Clicking on the error does nothing. I copied the error to a text editor, and it shows this path:

[image]

However, no such path exists:

[image]

I have tried everything from cleaning and rebuilding, deleting .vs folder, restarting pc.

Comment: you can try dotnet restore also delete bin and obj folders. Also have a backup.

Comment: Hey, I remember this kind of weird errors. This is usually because of the fact that your code has different kind of error but VS somehow cannot detect it. Try your code in different editor or do manual audit. You most probably have a syntax error in some place in your code. Poor performance on computer can cause Visual Studio to not working fully.

Comment: The other thing is that having extra projects in your solution may cause the problem too. What I suggest is that, check the references of your project. Broken reference can cause this problem too.

Comment: I have tried deleting bin / obj files, nothing happens.